# Remove css style from element

Tags: jquery

I would like to remove parent styling added by a css stylesheet using Jquery. I Googled but all I can find is removing *inline styles* or *classes*

HTML

```
<p><span>text</span></p>
```

CSS

```
p{
    width:300px;
    height:200px;
    border:solid 3px #000;
    padding:10px;
    font-size:23px;
}

span{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background: #ccc;
    padding:10px;
}
```

I tried many Jquery variations, one of them:

```
$('span').parent().removeAttr( 'style' );
```

[JsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/ecNAh/1/)

Answer (score 3):

you can not `removeAttribute` from `P` because there is no **inline css** or `style` attribute set for `P` tag.

You can overwrite default css using `.css()`

**What you can do.**

1. `$('span').parent('p').css({ width:350px;height:250px;border:solid 5px #000;padding:5px;font-size:20px;});`  overwrite rules as above
2. create `class` for parent `P` and use `.removeClass()`.

Comment: @Youss http://stackoverflow.com/questions/754607/can-jquery-get-all-css-styles-associated-with-an-element take a look at here. when you have css applied to dom just remove it instead of css2json

Answer (score 0):

apply cssClass to parent element and then by using removeClass in jQuery we can remove the class.

```
<p class="className"><span>text</span></p>


.className{
    width:300px;
    height:200px;
    border:solid 3px #000;
    padding:10px;
    font-size:23px;
}


    $('span').parent().removeClass( 'className' );
```

Comment: I know how to add and remove ClassName, I really would like to remove attribute styling instead

Comment: but  there is no inline css or style

Comment: The thing is Im scraping an external website. I cant get to its stylesheet, so I cant add a class name to attributes